# Uniquely Identify Method Call Stack in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am writing an application where I need to log the existing code. The codes are running in parallel environment. For logging purposes, I need to find call stacks distinct to each other, e.g:

```
public class ThreadedLogicClass
{
    public void MethodOneThreaded()
    {
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(1);
        MethodBase methodBase = frame.GetMethod();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadedLogic));
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void MethodOneNonThreaded()
    {
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(1);
        MethodBase methodBase = frame.GetMethod();

        this.NonThreadedLogic();
    }

    private void ThreadedLogic()
    {
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(1);
        MethodBase methodBase = frame.GetMethod();

        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.LastCall));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void NonThreadedLogic()
    {
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(1);
        MethodBase methodBase = frame.GetMethod();

        this.LastCall();
    }

    private void LastCall()
    {
        StackTrace trace = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame frame = trace.GetFrame(1);
        MethodBase methodBase = frame.GetMethod();
    }
}
```

Consider this main program:

```
ThreadedLogicClass obj = new ThreadedLogicClass();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(" =======> Calling MethodOneThreaded");
obj.MethodOneThreaded();
Console.WriteLine(" =======> End Calling MethodOneThreaded");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(" =======> Calling MethodOneNonThreaded");
obj.MethodOneNonThreaded();
Console.WriteLine(" =======> End Calling MethodOneNonThreaded");
```

From Here I need to Identify two unique call stacks and their various end points.

1.) MethodOneThreaded -> ThreadedLogic -> LastCall
2.) MethodOneNonThreaded -> NonThreadedLogic -> LastCall

What I want is to call a method call probably Like a begin/end call in the main method to log context and possibly some data associated with object inside a context.

Can someone guide me to a route where I can find more information on how to identify these two.

The reason to identify is to create separate context to store data in, till the end of the call stack I need to maintain that data to use later for Logging services.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A simpler approach is to use the ThreadStaticAttribute to store thread specific context.

Comment: @ShellShock, Kindly can you check the updated question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `StackFrame` and `StackTrace` diagnostic classes:

```
var frames = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
```

This will give you information about the whole call stack, including the IL and native code offsets. If you also want code line numbers, you'll need to have debugging information available (`pdb`s).

Note that optimization can make this rather surprising, since it will get rid of many method calls completely. If you've got some experience with WinDbg and similar tools, you can easily get the line numbers from the offsets, provided you keep the `pdb`s from the original build.

**UPDATE:**

Oh, you want to identify call stacks *across thread starts*? I'm affraid you're out of luck. There's no simple way of doing that, outside of creating a common wrapper class around the `Thread.Start` calls that will handle passing the required information inside the thread. .NET (nor Windows) doesn't keep track of who started which thread and where.

This can still be done to *look* somewhat elegant. If we assume there's no `await`s in the code, you can do something like this:

```
void Main()
{
  ThreadHelper.Start(() => Console.WriteLine(ThreadContext.CallerTrace.ToString()));
}

public static class ThreadHelper
{
  public static void Start(Action action)
  {
    var capturedStack = new StackTrace(1);

    new Thread(() => { ThreadContext.CallerTrace = capturedStack; action(); })
        .Start();
  }
}

public static class ThreadContext
{
  [ThreadStatic]
  public static StackTrace CallerTrace;
}
```

Using `ThreadHelper.Start` instead of `new Thread(...).Start()`, you can ensure that the stack information is captured *before* starting the new thread, and then passed inside. `ThreadStatic` static fields will be accessible from anywhere, while being different for different threads. You will of course want to join the *actual* call stack with the one captured in `ThreadContext.CallerTrace` *if there is any in the first place*.

Expanding this to work in a "begin ... end" fashion should be pretty trivial. You could use a "fake" disposable, and do something like this:

```
using (MethodCallLogger.Log(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()))
{
  // Do your stuff
}
```

The return value from `MethodCallLogger.Log` can than be a simple class that writes "begin" in the constructor, and "end" in the dispose method. It will of course have access to the full stack trace, including the one captured in `ThreadContext.CallerTrace`.

If you want to *wrap* the method call instead, you can make a simple helper method like this:

```
public static class MethodCallHelper
{
  public static void Log(Action action)
  {
    try
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Begin " + action.Method.ToString());

      action();
    }
    finally
    {
      Console.WriteLine("End " + action.Method.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luaan for the explanation.